# DynamoDB Mapper Query Doesn't Respect QueryExpression Limit

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Imagine the following function which is querying a GlobalSecondaryIndex and associated Range Key in order to find a limited number of results:

```
@Override
public List<Statement> getAllStatementsOlderThan(String userId, String startingDate, int limit) {

    if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(startingDate)) {
        startingDate = UTC.now().toString();
    }

    LOG.info("Attempting to find all Statements older than ({})", startingDate);

    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = Maps.newHashMap();
    eav.put(":userId", new AttributeValue().withS(userId));
    eav.put(":receivedDate", new AttributeValue().withS(startingDate));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<Statement> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Statement>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("userId = :userId and receivedDate < :receivedDate").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav)
            .withIndexName("userId-index")
            .withConsistentRead(false);

    if(limit > 0) {
        queryExpression.setLimit(limit);
    }

    List<Statement> statementResults = mapper.query(Statement.class, queryExpression);

    LOG.info("Successfully retrieved ({}) values", statementResults.size());

    return statementResults;
}

List<Statement> results = statementRepository.getAllStatementsOlderThan(userId, UTC.now().toString(), 5);

assertThat(results.size()).isEqualTo(5); // NEVER passes
```

The limit isn't respected whenever I query against the database. I always get back all results that match my search criteria so if I set the `startingDate` to `now` then I get every item in the database since they're all older than `now`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `queryPage` function instead of `query`.

From `DynamoDBQueryExpression.setLimit` documentation:

> Sets the maximum number of items to retrieve in each service request
>   to DynamoDB.
>
> Note that when calling DynamoDBMapper.query, multiple
>   requests are made to DynamoDB if needed to retrieve the entire result
>   set. Setting this will limit the number of items retrieved by each
>   request, NOT the total number of results that will be retrieved. Use
>   DynamoDBMapper.queryPage to retrieve a single page of items from
>   DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

As they've rightly answered the setLimit or withLimit functions limit the number of records fetched only in each particular request and internally multiple requests take place to fetch the results.

If you want to limit the number of records fetched in all the requests then you might want to use "Scan".

Example for the same can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html#:%7E:text=value%20of%20null.-,Example,-Map%3CString%2C%20AttributeValue)